# Polylang: How does the linking of right page by changing the attribute "href" work?

Tags: polylang

I have a question about linking the right page with *Polylang*.
I have a hard-coded anchor, which is basically a “back home” link.
It looks like this:

```
<a href=“magazin” class=“article-type-inner”><?php pll_e(‘Close’); ?></a>
```

I have already implemented a string and it works fine in the posts in both languages, but how can I change the “Href” to the right language?

For example my default language is English and the other language is French. If I am on a french post I will return to the English page… Is there any solution?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should not hardcode any strings or URL's, here is some options for you:

- Use pll_home_url() if your intention is to redirect to the home page. pll_home_url() accepts optional parameter $slug (2-letters code of the language) to switch between languages if needed.
- Use get_permalink(), the_permalink() or get_the_permalink(). You can pass page_id as first argument. Make sure post/pages/cpt's are linked properly. E.g. the_permalink(100).
- Worst case scenario - use if/else in combination with pll_current_language(). Not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

My answer: you can use function:

```
function the_permalink_md($post_id){

   $translations = pll_get_post_translations($post_id);
   $current_lang = pll_current_language('slug');

   echo get_the_permalink($translations[$current_lang]);
}

function the_title_md($post_id){

   $translations = pll_get_post_translations($post_id);
   $current_lang = pll_current_language('slug');

   echo get_the_title($translations[$current_lang]);
}
```

And theme files:

```
 <a href="<?php the_permalink_md($post_id); ?>"><?php the_title_md($post_id); ?></a>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**